# Habitat gulp default task copies all files

Tags: habitat

After downloading the habitat feature branch from github, running the gulp task 'default' copies over every file within a project file (.cs, .csproj, etc) into the web root rather than just the files it needs to run.

I am able to go through the gulp file and only just the bits I need, but I just need to check that this wasn't done by design.

https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/tree/feature/v9

Comment: This is not the default behaviour, at least it wasn't in previous branches, and looking at the gulpfile this has not changed in the v9 branch. The deploy works by calling `msbuild` so should not be copying those file over.